# Filter Magento Product collection for products that have a review

Tags: magento, collections

Hi as per title I want to filter for products that have a approved review.

Any help appreciated.

I have a feeling its based around the rating summary but not sure how to filter for that?

Thanks in advance.

Chris

Answer (score 0):

```
function getReviews() {
$reviews = Mage::getModel('review/review')->getResourceCollection();
$reviews->addStoreFilter( Mage::app()->getStore()->getId() )
                ->addStatusFilter( Mage_Review_Model_Review::STATUS_APPROVED )
                ->setDateOrder()
                ->addRateVotes()
                ->load();        

return $reviews;
```

}

Source: [Here](http://mandagreen.com/showing-all-reviews-and-ratings-on-a-page-in-magento/)

Comment: OH ok, I haven't been specific enough. I need to try to filter the actual product collection (thats used for a list) basically I'm wanting to use the pagination of the product collection and need to run the product collection rather than the review.

Comment: I don't think that you can filter our reviews from the product collection, but the link I posted should show you how to use a collection and merge it into a custom list.phtml